# EF core in Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, ef-core-2.0

I can't figure out how to create my DBContext.

I have context registred with DI :

```
services.AddDbContext<myContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("myContextConexionString "));
            });
```

Now my question is easy: how can I access from any other class method?

There is not a single example on MSDN outside “Put it on controller constructor and then just pass it around”

Edit :

To be more precise (As most people just add links to documentation I've already read) :

This is my class where I want to use DBContext :

```
public class MYclass
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        //get DBcontext here
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wtong with [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db?view=aspnetcore-2.1), for example?

Comment: It seems like you need to learn about Dependency Injection. And also separation of concerns. I'd take a look at [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B412). It's well worth the time it takes to watch it.

Comment: "And after more than 5 hours of research" which did not include reading any documentation and working through guides or examples, as it seems. Voting to close. Teach me basics = too broad.

Comment: @TomTom show me one link (just one) with documenttion on this ? I found none. All of them just add context in controller constructor and pass them along. I don't need this in my controller. I just want to use it when I need it

Comment: @YuriyN. this guide doesn't show how to use  DBcontext outside controller, again

Comment: @Jurion Because you are not supposed to use it outside of a DI configured class. Please [edit] your question and say exactly what you want to achieve if you want us to be able to help you.

Comment: Stadnard service locator, though assuming you have a HttpContext - which given how aspnet is supposed to be used is somehow valid. IF that is nont valid, use naother dependecy injection (the one provided is neither very good nor very flexible).

Comment: Your idea is wrong from the beginning. Web servers are not meant for long running tasks and what you are attempting will not work correctly with an injected DbContext. This question changed so much that I would suggest you to delete it and create a new one stating explicitly what you want to do rather than how you tried to solve the problem

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Exact ! That's why web service only lunches the task. Which will run in background. The service exits in less than 100ms.

Comment: @Jurion Then how is this running in the background? ASP.NET shouldn't be used for long running tasks. That should be done in some sort of background processor, perhaps implemented using bus messages (such as MassTransit)  or Hangfire. And those will have their own way of resolving dependencies.

Comment: @mason Basically, this project is to process imports/integration requests. We have 2 types : WebHooks, they call our webapp directly, fast, less than a 2-3 seconds per request. And there are sources without webhook, so it’s a polling. For polling, there is an Azure function on timer (every 15) which checks if polling is enabled for any of clients. If yes, it will fire a request to this server. This server will only check if there are actually new data, if yes, It writes a message to Azure ServiceBus, which is picked up by dedicated VM to process.

Comment: @mason The current difficulty with dbcontext is due to abstract nature of “integration processors” classes (basically one for every data source) and they are created on runtime using reflexion, so the developer only needs to write a subclass which can be in a completely different assembly. I just need a way to write “new DbContext()” using connexionString in appsettings.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of three ways of getting your DbContext into other classes.

1. Your controller can get the dependency and pass it into the other classes. This isn't very elegant, now your controller has to contain a lot of boilerplate for passing things around that don't directly concern it
2. Use a service locator pattern to have the class ask for the dependency from the IoC container. This is often considered an antipattern
3. The cleanest way to go about this is to have the class with the dependency be instantiated by the IoC container so it can resolve its dependencies.

Here's an example of the 3rd method:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    readonly MyDbContext _context;

    public MyService(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void DoSomeWork()
    {
        //Now you can use the context here
    }
}

public interface IMyService
{
    void DoSomeWork();
}

public class MyController : Controller
{
    readonly IMyService _myService;;

    public MyController(IMyService myService)
    {
        _myService = myService;
    }
}

//In your ConfigureServices method
services.AddDbContext<myContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("myContextConexionString"));
});

services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>();
```

By following this pattern, your controller doesn't need to know about the dependencies of MyService. It just has to ask for an IMyService via its constructor, and it it receives something that has all the dependencies needed fully resolved. [This video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B412) goes over this pattern more in depth.

Comment: It only moves a problem. It still requires something to add on controller constructor. It still doesn’t allows me to get my DBcontext when I need.

Comment: @Jurion No, it doesn't move the problem. It solves it. Please explain why you think this pattern won't work.

Comment: It will work, and it was the solution I found from official documentation. 
The service I’m developing uses about 15 different databases and contexts. I can’t (and I won’t) add all of them to all of controllers.

Comment: @Jurion Where in my question do you seem me adding any contexts *to the controller*? Look closely. I don't. The controller has to know nothing about how `IMyService` gets implemented. Stop throwing up road blocks. You spent less than 10 minutes looking at my answer. Read it closely. Try it. Watch the video I provided. I've been developing software professionally for years, as has Camilo. This pattern will work.

Comment: @mason public MyController(IMyService myService). So in my case it would be  public MyController(IMyService1 myService1,IMyService2 myService2,... IMyService15 myService15)

Comment: @Jurion A dependency on IMyService is not the same as a dependency on the DbContext. That's the whole point of the interface. The implementation details are separated out

Comment: @mason I spent less than 10 minuts reading it beacause I've already tried it 1 day ago. It is a right solution, but it doesn't work in my particular case.

Comment: In which case, please describe *your case* in more detail. Your question talks of a single DbContext and a single "service". Update it to be more specific so that a solution for *your case* can be provided.

Comment: @Jurion Yes, it will work for your case. Each service can consume as many different contexts as it needs. And if that service has too many dependencies, it can split its work into multiple subservices that also follow this same pattern, depending on them by interface instead of by implementation.

Comment: @mason So basically write code for nothing ? Can I just make “ServiceProvider” static on StartUp.cs and then just “ask” for context ? Will it break something ?

Comment: @Jurion No, I didn't  say write code for nothing. Actually watch the video I linked to. You're still not getting it. And yes, you could *ask* for the context, that's called the service locator pattern (technique #2 in my post). And it's considered an anti-pattern. It's better to know up front what your dependencies are. It makes testing a lot easier.

Comment: @mason Thank you for your help. I’ll chose option 4 : abandon .net core all together and go back to 4.7 where I can simply “using new DbContext()” and it will automagiclly use the right connection string.  PS : I'll watch the video. Seems very interesting

Comment: @Jurion What? That's ridiculous. You can construct a DbContext in .NET Core like that if you really wanted to. It's a terrible idea, because now your class isn't testable.

Comment: @mason Of cause it is ! It was the simplest way possible in 4.7 : The unit test project has a different connection string in config. The UnitTest assembly initialization creates a new, predefined database every time  (well, it copies it in my case) then you can test whatever you want in a controlled, predefined environment. The only “downside” the initialization of the test database takes about 5-6 seconds. I can live with that. Edit : test database is deleted if all tests passed

Comment: @Jurion Then that's not unit testing. That's integration testing. And still not a reason to abandon EF Core.

Comment: @mason Yes. it is more of integration testing. But in my experience, 95% of all code are CRUD operations with some checks (not empty name, value must be positive, etc etc). Maybe I jumped to .net core too early (The tooling is horrible, a lot of command line, creates 10 different frameworks versions on PC, updating nuget packages breaks visual studio and IIexpress. Took me some time to fix.). I like the startup time of app though. It seems a lot faster than 4.7. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help. I’ll stay a day or two on this before deleting everything and recreating from scratch.

Answer (score -1):

The `AddDbContext` call you do in Startup adds the context to the IoC container. You can then ask the IoC container to inject it into your controller like this

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly myContext _context;
    public MyController(myContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

and then use it to access your data.

Comment: The question was about "any other class method". I assume Jurion has some other classes that need to make use of the DbContext, instead of the controller directly using it. It might be worth explaining how that works.

Comment: It was not the question. It's oposite of the question. The question was : use it outside controller without adding context on controller

Comment: You can inject it into other classes as well, as long as the IoC container creates those classes.